# Not getting association bonus using google ID

Tags: support, association

I have one login (using my goggle login) and use two or three stack exchange sites. On stackoverflow I have a 3000 rep but I don't seem to be getting an association bonus on any of the other accounts.

So how does the association bonus work? And/or how do I associate the various accounts?

I've looked at the other association related questions and can't immediately see anything that applies

Comment: Your Stack Overflow account is not associated with your [other accounts](http://stackexchange.com/users/2176434/tom-tanner?tab=accounts). Probably you are using different login id for Stack Overflow. To see which login id are you using in Stack Overflow, go to your [SO account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1182921/tom-tanner) -> click on "my logins".

Comment: When you log in to your Stack Overflow account *add* your Google Id (click on the *my logins* link at the top-right-hand side, next to the *network profile* link). If that doesn't let you, register a new account with your Google ID on Stack Overflow and merge the accounts like outlined in the dupe link.

Comment: @hims056 - thanks - i was logging in to stackoverflow only using my defunct f/b account